# Iterating JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I've a JSON object like this

```
var Obj = {
    'id1': 'abc',
    'id2': 'pqr',
    'id3': 'xyz'
}
```

and I'm calling async method while iterating, like this

```
var otherObj = {};
for (i in Obj) {

    var someData = Obj[i];

    File.upload(someData).then(function(response) {
        otherObj[i] = response.data.url;
    });
}
```

But in this I'm getting otherObj as

```
otherObj = {
    'id3':'url1',
    'id3':'url2',
    'id3':'url3',
}
```

So my question is what is the best way to correctly associate each key present in `Obj` object with the response of `File.upload()`.

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript)

```
for (i in Obj) {

    var someData = Obj[i];
    (function(i) {
        File.upload(someData).then(function(response) {
            otherObj[i] = response.data.url;
        });
    })(i);
}
```

This will preserve `i` in the execution context of the callback for `File.upload().then`. What was happening before is each `File.upload().then` was 'seeing' the last iterated `i` which was visible to **all** callbacks.